# Submit form on Radio Button click in ASP.Net Core

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Using ASP.Net Core I have a page with a few radio buttons that would alter the display of the page and what I would like to do is if a user were to click the radio button the page would be refreshed to update the page with some new data based on whichever radio button (option) were clicked.

To achieve this would it be more suitable with a form submit?  Or more suitable to handle this interaction using JavaScript?

For a form submit I had tried something like this, but it doesnt submit the form:

```html
<form method="post" asp-action="MethodName" asp-controller="ControllerName">
        
     @foreach (var item in Model.FormOptions)
     {
         <input asp-for="@Model.SelectedFormOption" type="radio" value="@item.ID" /> @item.Name
     }
</form>
```

I could achieve the submit with a button however I'd prefer to submit the form on the click of the radio button.

Comment: Your `asp-for="FormOptions"` makes no sense, since your `@foreach` means that `FormOptions` is a collection of complex objects - a group of radio buttons bind to and posts back a simple value (and you never set the `checked` attribute when using TagHelper` - your model needs a property to bind to (say `int SelectedOption`)

Comment: Thank you Stephen, FYI:  In my actual solution the form is populated with a ViewModel containing an object list of Key/Value plus one extra attribute IsChecked, this is read from a table allowing the default checked value of the radio button list to be set in the DB.

Comment: Then it would be `<input asp-for="IsChecked"  .../>` (although that is an odd name for binding to an `int` which is what I assume `item.ID` is)

Comment: No in the db table for example, ID is an int, Name the description and IsChecked a boolean.

Comment: Then your code makes even less sense (and the `checked` attribute is a `boolean` attribute - i.e. its the presence of the attribute which determines what is selected - `checked="checked"` or `checked="true"` or `checked="false"` or `checked="anything"` all mean the same thing - that it will be checked. But since they are radio buttons, your code will set the last radio button to checked, no matter what the value of `IsChecked` is

Comment: You need a model containing a property `int SelectedOption` plus a `IEnumerable<T> FormOptions` property. And then its `<input asp-for="SelectedOption" type="radio" value="@item.ID"  />` which will correctly bind when you submit (and its the value of `SelectedOption` which will determine what is selected)

Comment: Ok thanks for your help Stephen.  I think we've gone off topic a little here, I'll take your suggstion on board though.  The code to populate radio buttons is working fine and is following most of the Microsoft tutorials and is binding to the model fine.  What I'm actually looking for is the correct solution to either post the form/fire some javascript to handle the click of the radio button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170834/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-simon).

Comment: Stephen pointed out I made a fundamental mistake while populating the radio buttons.  I've edited the code snippet accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type=radio]').click(function () {
        document.getElementById("formIDHere").submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One dirty trick to do it within HTML:

use `onclick="this.form.submit()"` directly on inputs...

```
<input asp-for="@Model.SelectedFormOption" type="radio" value="@item.ID" onclick="this.form.submit()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can take example:

```
 $('input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
   $("form").submit();
});
```